# The request after Subscription calling is not fired

Tags: angular, subscription

I need to call two services in the `OnInit` step. But the second request could not be sent And I was obliged to call them dependently, but I think this is not the proper coding.(All of the services sides of the backend are `Transient` )
This is my component.cs code (when the second service `this.planService` was not called):

```js
  planList: Array<any>;
  countActive: any;
  sub: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.referralService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.countActive = response.data;
      });
    this.planService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((r: any) => {
        this.planList = r.map(item => ({
          value: item.name, planDetail: {
            percentage: item.profitPercent,
            month: item.duration
          }
        }));
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

I decided to call them **dependently** (calling the second service in subscription) like below, but I think this is not wellformed:

```js
 
  ngOnInit() {
       this.sub = this.referralService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.countActive = response.data;
        this.planService
          .getAll()
          .pipe(first())
          .subscribe((r: any) => {
            this.planList = r.map(item => ({
              value: item.name, planDetail: {
                percentage: item.profitPercent,
                month: item.duration
              }
            }));
          });
      });
   }
```

referral.service.ts:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ReferralService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/referral/activeCount/`);
  }
}
```

plan.service.ts:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PlanService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get<Plan[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/plan`);
  }
}
```

I would be happy to find out why the first code sample does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't explain why in the first example subscription to `planService` didn't work. Technically speaking, they both *should* work. Perhaps something else is going on in `this.planService` that we don't see? Please elaborate `second request could not be sent`. What did you expect to happen, but did not happen?

Anyway to prettify this, we could use some rxjs to combine observables. Not having much contex I chose `combineLatest` so when each observable emits, we run tasks in `subscribe()`.

```js
  planList: Array<any>;
  countActive: any;
  unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {

      combineLatest(this.referralService.getAll(), this.planService.getAll())
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe([allReferrals, allPlans]) => {
        if (allReferrals) {
          this.countActive = allReferrals.data;
        }
        if (allPlans) {
          this.planList = allPlans.map(item => ({
            value: item.name, planDetail: {
              percentage: item.profitPercent,
              month: item.duration
            }
          })
        }
      }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.unsubscribe$.next();
  }
```

Comment: The second request does not call my backend service (its breakpoint doesn't hit) but if OnInit only call 'this.planService' with commenting this.sub, the service call properly

Comment: In addition, I tried your code. What happened every time I refresh the page, one of the services is called. For example, with the first refresh service 'this.referralService.getAll()' is called, and with the second refresh service 'this.planService.getAll()' is called

Comment: What is `this.planService` and `this.referralService` returning? An observable? Add those pieces to your example as well.

Comment: `this.planService` returns an integer value and `this.referralService` returns a list of class. Both of them are async.

Comment: If their not observables, then use plain old javascript for method calls. We have no need for subscriptions then either. Still, would be better if you just updated your code to include those parts as well - I think we're miscommunicating.

Comment: Let me know in which part do you ask me to update? Do you need the body of getAll()?

Comment: Add these methods: `this.referralService.getAll(), this.planService.getAll()`

Comment: I added them to the post